# How to redirect request from Apache Server to Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I am working on Tomcatcat Clustering with Apache server on Ubuntu14. I did Tomcat Clustering successful and integration with Apache server as well. 
In Apache server I did the virtual hosting as well something like following code.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myexample.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@myexample.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/myexample.com/public_html/
    ServerAlias www.myexample.com
    JkMount / balancer

    # Error page is just the index telling about the situation of not being connected
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

So when I request myexample.com it send the request to balancer and balancer further redirect this request to one Tomcat Worker. My worker.properties file looks like this.

```
# Define 1 real worker named ajp13
worker.list=balancer,stat
# Set properties for worker named ajp13 to use ajp13 protocol,
# and run on port 8109
worker.tomcat1.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat1.host=localhost
worker.tomcat1.port=8109
worker.tomcat1.lbfactor=10

worker.tomcat2.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat2.host=localhost
worker.tomcat2.port=8209
worker.tomcat2.lbfactor=10

worker.tomcat3.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat3.host=localhost
worker.tomcat3.port=8309
worker.tomcat3.lbfactor=10


worker.balancer.type=lb
worker.balancer.balance_workers=tomcat1,tomcat2,tomcat3

worker.stat.type=status
```

Now the problem is whenever I request myexample.com, request is redirect to Tomcat Root folder and shows the Root folder content. I have one web application(helloworld) inside webapps folder of each tomcat instance.

So my question is how can I configure Tomcat or Apache so that request should redirect go to helloworld instead of Root folder.